# Changing the name of an existing Facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

How do I change the name of a group in Facebook? It has approximately 200 member and was set up a while back.

The current name is "We Made Thursdays" and I'm trying to work out how to have it now be "Phat Nights".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are the admin,

1. Go to the group's page
2. Click on **Edit Group** from the right
   [image]
3. Edit the **Group Name** at the middle of the page
   [image]
4. Click **Save** at the bottom of the page

Comment: FB does not let you change group names if there are more than 250 users, and its a real let down for many group owners.